# Optimization not being turned off

Tags: visual-studio

I am seeing a weird issue today where even if the project properties have "Optimized Code" turned-off, the resulting assembly turns out optimized. This prevents hitting breakpoints while debugging.

Tried clearing the bin/object folders, and deleting the .vs folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlYyU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is with breakpoints, you can try these:

1. Have you switched it to a release configuration? If so, switch it back to the debug mode
2. Debug->Options->Debugging->General->Enable 'Enable .NET Framework source stepping'
3. Debug->Options->Debugging->General->Disable 'Just My Code'
4. Tools->Options->Debugging and Enable 'Managed Compatibility Mode'